# In Gitlab why we are using the particular image if we already have gitlab runner to run the code

Tags: gitlab

I am new to Gitlab, and bit confuse with the Gitlab Image keyword..

If we already have gitlab runners specified to run the commands they why are we separately use Image keywords in the gitlab-ci.yml (in Any stage or Jobs)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdq3u.jpg)

Comment: You can use Docker Images ready to use for your purpose, in this way the pipeline execution time will be lower instead install anytime all you need. You can find the Image that fit for you in Dockerhub or build your own

Answer (score 1):

One important concept to be aware of is that there are a few different [executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) that a gitlab-runner may use. On `gitlab.com`, a `docker+machine` executor is used. The docker/kubernetes executors are the only context where the `image:` keyword is relevant.

When jobs run in these executor types, they do not run directly in the host context of the runner. Instead, a docker container is created to run each job. For this, a Docker image must be used. The default image works for general use cases, but you may want to choose a different ready-made image for your use. This can make your environment more repeatable as well as reduce job times by avoiding time that would otherwise need to be spent installing software requirements.

For example, if I have a job that builds python software, I may choose to use `image: "python:3.10.2"` because it will contain the Python runtime and tools I need for building Python software.

By contrast, if you are using a `shell` executor, your jobs execute directly in the host -- you can simply use software available on the runner host itself and there is no `image:` to choose.